# Multilevel regression model for nested data using "multilevel" and "lme4" R packages?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

**Hypothesis 1**
**Independent variable** = Thermal inertia (TI)
**Dependent variable** = Depth diameter ratio (d/D), Radii variation (RV) and Rim irregularity (RI).
**Hypothesis 2**
**Independent variable** = Thermal inertia (TI)
**Dependent variable** = Mantled Rim percentage (MRI)
For testing hypothesis 1, I have to test correlation of d/D, RV and RI with thermal inertia.
For 2nd hypothesis Correlation of MRP with thermal inertia.
Total craters = 138 (ID), Scenes (group) = 18. Repeated measurements were taken for each crater. Craters are nested within scenes, TI values are nested within scenes, and collected data (d/D, RV, RI, MRP) nested within scenes.
I have to compare TI both within and between scenes, also the statistical significance of each model result determined using a likelihood ratio test to attain p-values. Since I am new to R and statistics, if anyone could help me in understanding the design it will be of great help to me.
I have to look for p-values and results supporting hypothesis1 or 2?

[image: Data for hypothesis testing]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see of your data and the descriptions, you do not have multiple measures within `ID`. You have measured several variables, `D_d`, `RI`, `RV`, and `MRP` once for each `ID`.

Thus `ID` seems is the unit of measurements (that is, it unique to each row in your data).

However you do seem to have multiple measures within `Group`, and therefore a model with random intercepts for `Group` would seem to be appropriate. I would therefore suggest the following model as a starting point:

```
lmer(TI ~ D_d + RI + RV + MRP + (1 | Group), data = ... )
```

This will estimate fixed effects for `D_d`, `RI`, `RV`, and `MRP`, along with a variance for the random `Group` variable, which will account for the non-independence of measurements within each group.

Comment: Here ID represents the crater number, the craters are organized by the Group that cover them. example: 5 craters cover group A. I tried the model described by you, but I am not getting the correct p-values. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @Farzana OK that is what I thought, so ID is nested in Group, but each ID/crater has it's measurements taken only once. That is, each row represents one crater.

Comment: Each ID consists of measurement of 5 cases (i.e. TI, RV,RI,D_d and MRP), error were determined based on repeat measurements of a particular crater.

Comment: @Farzana so you measured TI, RV,RI,D_d and MRP 5 times for each crater ? Or you measured them all once for each crater

Comment: No, I measured it (TI,RI,RV,D_d,MRP) once for each crater.

Comment: I would like to add one more thing here, the data is not balanced i.e. D_d has some missing values. I tried the model suggested by you and an error comes up as "models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset".

Comment: @Farzana "No, I measured it (TI,RI,RV,D_d,MRP) once for each crater.". Then you don't have repeated measures within ID (as I have been saying),  and you can go ahead and fit the model I suggested. The error you quoted does not seem like it comes from `lmer` and is likely a different problem. How exactly does that arise ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104078/discussion-between-farzana-and-robert-long).

Comment: Let us [continue the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104078/discussion-between-farzana-and-robert-long)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of points:

- Mixed models are indeed used to account for correlations in your outcome variable, I guess `TI` within the levels of grouping/cluster variables, i.e., `ID` and `Group` in your case. Assuming that normal error terms would be adequate for `TI`, you could use a linear mixed model. For example, using function `lmer()` from package **lme4**, e.g.,

  ```
  fm1 <- lmer(TI ~ RI + (1 | Group / ID), data = tisia)
  ```

  If you are going also to load the **lmerTest** package, you will obtain a p-value for the association between `TI` and `RI`.
- Model `fm1` above postulates that the correlation between any pair of measurements of `TI` within the same combination of levels of `ID` and `Group` is the same. If instead, you want to assume that the correlations within the same combination of `ID` and `Group` decay as the difference in `RI` values increases, then you could include the random slope for `RI`, i.e.,

  ```
  fm2 <- lmer(TI ~ RI + (RI | Group / ID), data = tisia)
  ```
- You could compare the two models to see if this improves the fit using a likelihood ratio test implemented by the `anova()` function, i.e.,

  ```
  anova(fm1, fm2)
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I followed your instruction and tried applying those models in r, but an error message pops up which states : Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations, how to resolve this error?

Comment: Couple of things: 1) Did you code your two grouping variables in such a way that they are distinct?  Imagine that in Group A, there are 5 IDs, 100-104, and then in Group B, there also 5 IDs, 100-104. This shouldn't be a problem if you have the nesting correct, but it's always a good idea to give IDs unique and distinct values across groups. 2) Try running the random effects as `(1|Group) + (1|ID)`. What happens? Are the reported Ns of each of these categories correct?